# assign integers as variables

Tags: php, mysql

Generic topic I know. Its hard to be specific in a topic. Anyway I have problem with this sql logic:

```
"SELECT * FROM imagecomment WHERE filename = :filename ORDER BY comment_timestamp DESC LIMIT '$min', '$max'";
```

When I try the same logic but with integers directly in the sql logic it works. The variables min and max are integers:

int(10)
int(20) I get this when var_dump() them. I also tried to bindValue() the variables (as I usually do) to two parameters but it still didn't work.

Comment: do not escape your LIMIT values

Comment: Don't need single quotes around them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using this in a PDOStatement, right? (since you're using :filename)

`$db = new PDO(); //assume you have this set`

```
$stmt = $db->prepare(
         "SELECT * 
          FROM imagecomment 
          WHERE filename = :filename 
          ORDER BY comment_timestamp 
          DESC LIMIT :min, :max";

$stmt->bindValue(':filename', $filename);
$stmt->bindValue(':min', $min);
$stmt->bindValue(':max', $max);

$stmt->execute();
```

And you should be able to fetch your results, If that doesn't work, let me know what error you're getting back from the PDOStatement.

Comment: I'm not getting any result set when using parameters instead of integers directly in the sql logic "SELECT * FROM imagecomment WHERE filename = :filename ORDER BY comment_timestamp DESC LIMIT :min, :max"; and bind the values to the parameters exactly as you've done. I've also been told before that I should just insert integers directly. Whats your thoughts about this?

Answer (score 4):

```
 "SELECT * FROM imagecomment
 WHERE filename = :filename ORDER BY comment_timestamp DESC LIMIT $min, $max";
```